# Why does 0 in a GET request evaluate to True in a Django 1.10 form?

Tags: python, django, forms, get, boolean

I am passing a GET request to a Django form that contains the parameter "favorite."  When I do localhost:8000?favorite=1, it works fine.  1 evaluates to True, just as I expect.  However, when I do localhost:8000?favorite=0, 0 evaluates to True as well, which is not what I expect.  When I look at request.GET['favorite'] directly, before it is evaluated by the FavoriteForm class, I see that it equals 0.  However, the FavoriteForm class seems to be converting this to True, and I don't know why.  I assume that it is treating 0 as a string, and it evaluates all strings to True, but it does not make sense that this is how they would have set it up, because it is counterintuitive, so I imagine there must be something else going on, like some misconfiguration of my form or something.  Ideas?

**forms.py**

```
class FavoriteForm(forms.Form):
    favorite = forms.BooleanField()
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = FavoriteForm(request.GET)
favorite = form.cleaned_data['favorite']
print favorite #This returns True if request.GET['favorite'] == 0
print request.GET['favorite'] #This returns 0 as expected
```

**query**

http://localhost:8000?favorite=0

Comment: Also, if I do  def clean(self):
  cleaned_data = super(FavoriteForm, self).clean()
  favorite = cleaned_data.get("favorite")
  raise Exception(favorite), this returns True as well, so it seems that  the clean method is what is messing things up.

Comment: Check that `cleaned_data.get("favorite")` isn't returning a `str`, as any non-empty string (even `"0"`) is truthy.

Comment: Wait, I just checked raise Exception(bool("0")), and it evaluated to True.  Wtf?

Comment: @kloddant `bool("0")` evaluates to True because `"0"` is a string, hence truthy, as stated above. Try `bool("False")`. It also evaluates to True. If you really want to see the boolean value of `0` do this: `bool(int("0"))`, returns False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print favorite`
return True it means that 0, 1 or et.c is string
for get right result write your like this:
query

http://localhost:8000?favorite=true

or

http://localhost:8000?favorite=false

Comment: Oh, that worked now!  I swear I tried that, and it returned True.  Okay, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great :)  Not at all

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well I have a solution, but I don't like it.  It involves modifying request.GET to evaluate any strings to booleans before it is passed to the form class.  Since request.GET never returns anything that is not a string, it seems like Django should really be treating "0" as 0 in its form classes.

**utils.py**

```
def boolean(string):
    response = None
    if string is 0 or string is None:
        response = False
    if string is 1:
        response = True
    if isinstance(string, basestring):
        if string.lower() in ["0", "no", "false"]:
            response = False
        if string.lower() in ["1", "yes", "true"]:
            response = True
    return response
```

**forms.py**

```
class FavoriteForm(forms.Form):
    favorite = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

**views.py**

```
from utils import boolean

if request.method == 'GET':
    if 'favorite' in request.GET:
        request.GET._mutable = True
        request.GET['favorite'] = boolean(request.GET['favorite'])
```